# Compatibility of JMeter To Test Java-based ERP

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, zk, adempiere

Can anybody tell me whether i can use JMeter 2.12 to test performance of a system which is developed using ADempiere ERP framework, ZK Ajax?

For UIs system `.zuk` files are used.

All these tools and methodologies are java-based ones.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can use detailed, step-by-step instructions to test ZK using jmeter:

- [Execute a Loading or Performance Test on ZK using JMeter](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/January/Execute_a_Loading_or_Performance_Test_on_ZK_using_JMeter)
- [Perform stress test on ZK using JMeter-take Shopping Cart as an example](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2012/May/Perform_stress_test_on_ZK_using_JMeter-take_Shopping_Cart_as_an_example)
- [ZK JMeter Plugin](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2013/08/06/zk-jmeter-plugin/)
- [Record JMeter Testing Script for ZK](http://ben-bai.blogspot.com/2013/12/record-jmeter-testing-script-for-zk.html)

as well as discussion entries:

- [Testing ZK with JMeter](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/54049/testing-zk-with-jmeter/)
- [Performance test using zk framework using jmeter](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/86876/performance-test-using-zk-framework-using-jmeter/)